# How to get dropdown values in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi everyone I'm working on PHP appliaction where I populate a dropbox based on another drop box selection using **javascript**- everything works fine but the second dropbox values is *numbers*, my question is How can I set the values of the second dropbox to be **text** not *numbers* which is I get.

I have the following code for dropdown box:

```
    <!-- Our food group drop down-->
   <select id="foodgroups" onchange="selectFoods(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id)">
        <option id="1" value="">Select a Food Group</option>
        <option id="2"value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
        <option id="3" value="Vegetables">Vegetables</option>
        <option id="4" value="Meat">Meat</option>
        <option id="5" value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
        <option id="6" value="Grains">Grains</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Our foods for a group selection (empty on default) -->


 <select id="foods" name="selectedFoodItem"></select>
```

Here is the function that populates the second dropdown

```
 function selectFoods(foodGroup) {
        // Get a reference to the foods select.
        var foodsSelect = document.getElementById("foods");

        // Create a two dimension array containing foods for each group.
        var foods = [["Banana","Grapes","Oranges","Watermelon"],
                    ["Brocolli", "Califlower","Spinach","Tomatoes"],
                    ["Beef", "Chicken", "Turkey", "Tuna"],
                    ["Cheese", "Ice Cream", "Milk", "Yogurt"],
                    ["Bread", "Pasta", "Rice", "Quinoa"]];

        if ((foodGroup >= 0) && (foodGroup <= foods.length)) {
            foodsSelect.options.length = 0;

            // Index was in range, so access our array and create options.
            for (var i = 0; i < foods[foodGroup - 1].length; i++) {
               foodsSelect.options[foodsSelect.options.length] = new Option(foods[foodGroup - 1][i], i);
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried to access the value in php `$val = $_POST['selectedFoodItem'];`
I get the index

Thank you!

Comment: try `onchange="selectFoods(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the ID's start on 2 (the valid ones) and your foods selection index start at two, just get the ID then `- 2`, after the function run, then use that as the index inside your array selection and loop all those values inside to create the markup:

```
function selectFoods(foodGroup) {
    // Get a reference to the foods select.
    var foodsSelect = document.getElementById("foods");

    // Create a two dimension array containing foods for each group.
    var foods = [["Banana","Grapes","Oranges","Watermelon"],
                ["Brocolli", "Califlower","Spinach","Tomatoes"],
                ["Beef", "Chicken", "Turkey", "Tuna"],
                ["Cheese", "Ice Cream", "Milk", "Yogurt"],
                ["Bread", "Pasta", "Rice", "Quinoa"]];

    var options = '';
    var selected = foodGroup.id - 2; // get the ID minus 2
    var l = foods[selected].length;
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++) { // loop foods and get the selected thru the index selected
        options += '<option value="' + foods[selected][i] + '">' + foods[selected][i] + '</option>';
    }

    foodsSelect.innerHTML = options;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/Meqmgt)

Comment: I'd like to suggest one change. Don't recount length in the for-loop. Store the value in a variable before the for-loop and use that instead.

Comment: @RST there, much better

Comment: Thank you Ghost your solution really worked for me. #KeepKooKeeng

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code gets the index rather than the string value you expect because of this line of code:

```
new Option(foods[foodGroup - 1][i], i);
```

the first argument is the value you see in the select, while the second is the value that gets submitted to the server side. In your example, one of the options will be rendered as follows:

```
<option value="0">Brocolli</option>
```

If you want your server side to receive `"Broccoli"` change the Option code as follows:

```
new Option(foods[foodGroup - 1][i], foods[foodGroup - 1][i]);
```

which results in:

```
<option value="Brocolli">Brocolli</option>
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/4298w4ob/

Comment: It is "Broccoli", btw.

Comment: Thanks Danilo :) you the best,

Answer (score 1):

Change this script code.

```
function selectFoods(foodGroup) {
        // Get a reference to the foods select.
        var foodsSelect = document.getElementById("foods");

        // Create a two dimension array containing foods for each group.
        var foods = [["Banana","Grapes","Oranges","Watermelon"],
                    ["Brocolli", "Califlower","Spinach","Tomatoes"],
                    ["Beef", "Chicken", "Turkey", "Tuna"],
                    ["Cheese", "Ice Cream", "Milk", "Yogurt"],
                    ["Bread", "Pasta", "Rice", "Quinoa"]];

        if ((foodGroup > 1) && ((foodGroup-1) <= foods.length)) {
            foodsSelect.options.length = 0;

            // Index was in range, so access our array and create options.
            for (var i = 0; i < foods[foodGroup - 2].length; i++) {

               foodsSelect.options[foodsSelect.options.length] = new Option(foods[foodGroup - 2][i], foods[foodGroup - 2][i]);
            }

        }
}
```

You will get your required answer. :)